# Windows10 boot option lost after installing ubuntu 15.04 and try boot repair

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, boot-repair

I installed ubuntu 15.04 alongside windows 10 on laptop lenovo E440, but I can't enter to windows 10. And I launched boot-repair but now there is no windows 10 boot option. Else, I tried access from UEFI windows boot manager but the result still the same. 
Here log from boot-repair http://paste.ubuntu.com/12693158/
Have any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: You can't enter Windows 10? What does this mean? Can you not see it, even in the Windows boot manager or do you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your Windows bootloader seems to have been renamed to bootmgfw2.efi.  Rename it back, then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and see if you get a Windows boot menu item.  Try it. Try turning off secure boot.  Try the efi boot menu (some function key at power-on, like f12, or f10) and select the Windows option.

Comment: You also are showing two efi partitions. You should only have one per device. Use gparted and remove boot flag from sda7.

Comment: Two ESPs are perfectly legal, but some tools can become confused by that. (The Windows installer is the only example that springs to mind.) In any event, ubfan1's suggestions are all good ones. I'll add that there's an `EFI/Lenovo/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` file that might be involved in the boot process -- it's conceivable that Lenovo has configured Windows to boot through that rather than `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`. If so, you'd need to create a manual GRUB entry to launch the Lenovo variant -- or ditch the pre-installed Windows and re-install it with a stock version to avoid the weirdness.

Comment: sorry for not responding too long, it seems alert email is not working.

Comment: Actually after searching for answer and try by my self, it was uefi problem. Firstly, I try to do repair of windows boot my inserting windows cd, but its not work. At the first time, there are list of restore point that has been made by windows automatically, and I chose the last one but it was failed.

Comment: and in the next boot, the list of restore point was gone. Finally after changes the order of boot from uefi, which is put windows in the first order, I can logon to windows directly after restarting my laptop. Right now, I am not fix grub menu of ubuntu yet, but thank you for ubfan1, oldfred and Rod Smith. It also happen to another laptop that has dual boot (windows 10 and ubuntu), but it was different case. I can't boot to ubuntu, and it was fix by choose 'the right' ubuntu menu in uefi and fix the order of boot menu. There were 2 ubuntu option in uefi menu.

Comment: So my conclusion is try to change order of uefi boot menu if there is a problem with dual boot. Thank you all.